# is there any one wallet that can hold both Ethereum and solana,

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, dapp

I want to interact with both ethereum and solana blockchain in my web application. Is there any one wallet that works for both dapps and is supported by a library like wallet adapter

Answer (score 2):

backpack!

https://github.com/coral-xyz/backpack

you can download the edge build and then drag and drop into chrome extension to play around with it

https://github.com/coral-xyz/backpack/releases

[image]